# Why is $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(2-4X+3X^2+3X^3)$ a torsion module, and why is its annihilator $(2-4X+3X^2+3X^3)\triangleleft\mathbb{Q}[X]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be the $\mathbb{Q}[X]$-module $F/N$ where $F=\mathbb{Q}[X]^3$ and $N$ is the submodule of $F$ generated by $$\{(1-X,X,1+X),(1+X,1-X,2X),(X,1,1)\}.$$ Then the invariant factor decomposition of $M$ is: $M\cong\mathbb{Q}[X]/(2-4X+3X^2+3X^3)$.

It is said in my notes that $M$ is a torsion module and $$\mathrm{ann}_R(M)=(2-4X+3X^2+3X^3)\triangleleft\mathbb{Q}[X].$$

I cannot figure out why is $M$ a torsion module?

And why is $\mathrm{ann}_R(M)=(2-4X+3X^2+3X^3)\triangleleft\mathbb{Q}[X]$? Should we create a map $$M\to\mathbb{Q}[X]/(2-4X+3X^2+3X^3)$$ to explain this? I have no clue, could anyone please help in the reasoning and explanation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where all that's necessary is to follow the definition of "torsion module" and "annihilator" (also, "*the ideal generated by <ring elements>*" is, of course, always an ideal). Maybe it's easier to think of a simpler example first: do you understand why, as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a torsion module, and that $\mathrm{ann}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})=n\mathbb{Z}$?

In fact, it is more generally true that for any ring $R$ and any ideal $I\subseteq R$ that isn't the zero ideal, the $R$-module $M=R/I$ is torsion, and $\mathrm{ann}_R(M)=I$. There is nothing special about the module or polynomial in your question.

Comment: 1+ for "There is nothing special about the module or polynomial in your question."